# $\int \frac{dx}{a\sin x + b \cos x} $ using complex numbers

Tags: integration, complex-numbers

I want to do the following integral using complex numbers:

$$\int \frac{dx}{a\sin x + b \cos x} $$

Specifically, I plan on using Euler's form :
$$e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x$$

Then, $$(a\sin x + b\cos x)^{-1} = \Re((b-ia)e^{ix})^{-1})$$ 
The integrand then reduces to a simple exponential

$$\int \frac{(b+ai)e^{-ix} dx}{b^2 + a^2} = \frac{1}{-i}\frac{(b+ai)e^{-ix}}{b^2 + a^2} + C$$

Neglecting the constant and going back to the $a+ib$ form,
$$\frac{(-a+bi)(\cos x - i\sin x)}{a^2 + b^2}$$

The real part of which, on simplifying, yields $$\frac{-a\cos x +b\sin x}{a^2+b^2}$$

This is all very good except that it's far far away from the actual answer. What did I miss?

For reference, the actual answer contains a logarithm of a tan of a linear expression in $x$. I know that is correct as I have reached that answer using other methods.

Comment: taking the real part then inverse is different from inverse then take the real part.

Answer (score 1):

Make the following substitution
$z=e^{ix}$ and $a+i b=\rho e^{i\phi}$
This integral has the following form
$$
I=\frac{2}{\rho e^{i\phi}}\int\frac{dz}{z^2-e^{-2i\phi}}=\frac{1}{\rho }\int dz(\frac{1}{z-e^{-i\phi}}-\frac{1}{z+e^{-i\phi}})=\frac{1}{\rho}\log\frac{z-e^{-i\phi}}{z+e^{-i\phi}}
$$